# I need an arc vector for custom collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, xml, vector, toolbar, drawable

I need an arc vector that I could anchor on the bottom of my toolbar to make it look like this:

https://androidexample365.com/content/images/2018/12/ArcLayout.jpg

Image is from androidexample365

Thank you so much to anyone who will help.

Comment: check this https://github.com/florent37/ArcLayout

Comment: I actually only want a vector xml of this

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49725237/7666442

Answer (score 0):

Here is an arc vector for custom collapsing toolbar as you need

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="500dp"
android:height="500dp"
android:viewportWidth="500"
android:viewportHeight="500">

<path
    android:fillColor="#000000"
    android:fillAlpha="0"
    android:strokeColor="#000000"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#000000"
    android:fillAlpha="0"
    android:strokeColor="#000000"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#389282"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M185.94 399.69C268.86 381.15 373.54 400.53 500 457.84L500 500L0 498.71L0 457.84C41.04 437.61 103.02 418.23 185.94 399.69Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#000000"
    android:fillAlpha="0"
    android:strokeColor="#389282"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M185.94 399.69C268.86 381.15 373.54 400.53 500 457.84L500 500L0 498.71L0 457.84C41.04 437.61 103.02 418.23 185.94 399.69Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#389282"
    android:fillAlpha="0"
    android:strokeColor="#389282"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M185.94 399.69C268.86 381.15 373.54 400.53 500 457.84L500 500L0 498.71L0 457.84C41.04 437.61 103.02 418.23 185.94 399.69Z" />
```

another one is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="500dp"
android:height="500dp"
android:viewportWidth="500"
android:viewportHeight="500">

<path
    android:fillColor="#000000"
    android:fillAlpha="0"
    android:strokeColor="#000000"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#000000"
    android:fillAlpha="0"
    android:strokeColor="#000000"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#389282"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M185.94 72.51C268.86 85.91 373.54 71.9 500 30.48L500 0L0 0.93L0 30.48C41.04 45.1 103.02 59.11 185.94 72.51Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#000000"
    android:fillAlpha="0"
    android:strokeColor="#389282"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M185.94 72.51C268.86 85.91 373.54 71.9 500 30.48L500 0L0 0.93L0 30.48C41.04 45.1 103.02 59.11 185.94 72.51Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#389282"
    android:fillAlpha="0"
    android:strokeColor="#389282"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M185.94 72.51C268.86 85.91 373.54 71.9 500 30.48L500 0L0 0.93L0 30.48C41.04 45.1 103.02 59.11 185.94 72.51Z" />
```

Here is some suggestion for vector image which I'm follow

first of all, [create SVG file online](https://vectr.com/) as you need then [convert it into a vector](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/), it's simple :)