# Show a part of the image in Parent layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

[image]

I want to design a layout where a part of the image should be visible in the layout.

I am using Constraint Layout.I want to design the image provided.I have the green round image available with me.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_green"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your expected output ?

Comment: The expected output is that of the image i have posted in my question

Comment: Then whats the output you are getting ?

Comment: The image is showing half with respect to the Y axis. The code is in my question .Can you plz help me out where I did get wrong?

Comment: @SuvartheeChakravarti check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49725237/7666442

Comment: I think you need to create drawable xml. Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49724329/how-can-i-recreate-this-background-in-xml/49725237#49725237 . Or   https://android.jlelse.eu/android-shape-drawables-tutorial-17fbece6fef5

Comment: @NileshRathod creating another layer in the last option i want to try.I want to do it with the image provided to me. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: @SuvartheeChakravarti also check this **[ArcLayout](https://github.com/florent37/ArcLayout)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the image that you posted, it looks like you have an oversized circle with the center place at or near the top of the enclosing layout. Here is one way to accomplish this layout.

Create the oversized circle by specifying the following in the *ImageView*:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1.5"
```

Create a *Space* widget in the center of the layout. Constrain the bottom of the *ImageView* to the top of the *Space*. (See the layout, below.) The circle can now be moved up and down by changing the vertical bias of the *Space* widget. The placement can be made statically in the XML or dynamically in code.

Here is that the result looks like as the bias is changed on the *Space* widget:

[image]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_green"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/space"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1.5" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.40" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**round_green.xml**

```
<shape 
    android:shape="oval">
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:centerColor="#79FFD6"
        android:endColor="#79FFD6"
        android:startColor="#A5F74D" />
</shape>
```

Although this will give you the layout you are looking for, it may be problematic as you change to different devices or display in landscape. Depending upon your actual requirements, you may want to consider the options presented in the comments as more robust solutions.