# Implementing a certain shape in android

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am new to android and am designing an app which has a login screen which has a similar design as shown below. I'm not sure how to implement the oval.
I tried making an oval using shape.xml. It works fine on small devices. But when I test it on large devices like Pixel C, It doesnt scale properly.

[image]

Code of shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">


<gradient
    android:startColor="#6699ff"
    android:endColor="#9900ff"
    android:angle="0" />

<size
    android:width="120dp"
    android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```

The output I'm getting for large device

[image]

Output for smaller devices which is fine
[image]

Comment: Try giving negative margins in your layout xml, along with `match_parent`.

Comment: check this :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49725237/7666442

Comment: Add that curve image as background and put them in different drawable folder to test. @Darryl

Comment: Use seperate layouts for small and large screens! That way you can control and see how each looks more easily

Comment: @Brandon That's not the right way for this particular scenario. It can still look like an oval in some screens. Best way is to use negative margins as Nilesh and myself suggested.