# How to fix background image with drawable xml file on Android?

Tags: android, xml, drawable

How do I make [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtrTu.png) in android drawable.xml format?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/wallpaper"></bitmap>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/android/adding_images_to_android.html

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49724329/how-can-i-recreate-this-background-in-xml/49725237#49725237

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drawable will expand to fit your container. Notice that I didn't modify the bottom inset (`android:bottom`) so that the curve remains flush with the bottom of your container. You can modify the `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` attributes to get your desired curve.

**rounded_header.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="-100dp"
        android:left="-400dp"
        android:right="-400dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#F07B26"
                android:endColor="#F8BA4C"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_header"/>
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can defined the drawable directly as layer-list item:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:opacity="opaque">

    <!-- The background color, preferably the same as your normal theme -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wallpaper"/>

    </layer-list>
```

Comment: I don't want to use the picture in the drawable folder.
How can I make these images in xml?
I want to draw shapes using xml. Thank you.

Comment: I want to create wallpaper file in xml with drawable folder